# Linq Queries converting to lambda expressions ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

`from item in range where item % 2 ==0 select i ;`

extension methods equivelant  of it is.

`range.where(item % 2 ==0).select(x=>x)`.

I feel that first way of linq is translating next one by compiler and if it is,so is there any optimization by compiler like this `range.where(item & 2 == 0)` instead of other one ?

Comment: All of above queries are returning same results if you write it manually. But compiler does not have an idea about what is inside the select method. so it will not optimise up to that level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the C# compiler will not ever remove the `.Select` call at the end of the LINQ query.  The reason why is that the C# compiler has no knowledge of what the `.Select` method does and hence cannot remove it as an optimization.

The compiler cannot have this knowledge because it binds to `Select` in a very flexible way.  It will consider any instance or extension method named `Select` on the target type which has the appropriate signature.  You can even define your own `Select` methods to do customized actions like logging.  If the C# compiler removed the `Select` clause in this case it would break this type of code.

Comment: all these queries which i wrote has same result ?

Comment: @Freshblood, I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: Yes, these three query produce same result that was what i asked.